# Differences between Serial Ports on Windows and Linux - .NET/Mono

Tags: c#, linux, windows, mono, serial-port

I'm working on a c# .NET program that I will eventually be running in Mono on Linux.  I'm developing in C# on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2017.  I'll be moving it to Linux (Ubuntu for testing, Yocto for testing and deployment) running the latest Mono (5.4) when ready.

In the application I use 2 COM ports from **System.IO.Ports**.  Nothing really fancy.  The ports are used to control external hardware.  The COM ports currently are via USB-to-RS-232 adapters.

```
comDevice = new SerialPort();

if (isWindows())
{
    //- Windows
    comDevice.PortName = "COM15";
}
else
{
    //- Linux
    comDevice.PortName = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
}

comDevice.BaudRate = 19200;
comDevice.DataBits = 8;
comDevice.Parity = Parity.None;
comDevice.StopBits = StopBits.One;
comDevice.Handshake = Handshake.None;
comDevice.ReadBufferSize = 1024;
```

Nothing fancy.  Pretty basic port setup.

Everything works as expected when I hook the devices up to a Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) box and use a terminal program (PuTTY).  To one of the devices I can issue 2 commands:

- 'O'  -- Turn the device ON
- 'C'  -- Turn the device OFF

The device responds with "O'OK" when I turn it on.  I see "C'OK" when I turn it off.  When I issue a command to make the device do something it returns the readings that I expect:

- 'D'  -- Do programmed event

...the device beeps, and the response comes back "D'23.215^0131".

In Windows, The "O" and "C" command appear to work just fine in PuTTY and in my code.  However, when I issue the "D" command I get "D" back after a device beep.  No additional data is returned in either my code, PuTTY, or any COM program I have tried in Windows 10.

I don't believe it to be an RTS/CTS thing.  I don't see that those lines are hooked up in the adapter.  I do have my application dumping their state in my log file just in case.

I guess I could be wrong, but it smells like the Linux COM ports are "doing something" automagically that the Windows ports are waiting for me to do manually.  I'm wondering if anyone else has done any Windows/Linux Mono work using COM ports and may know something that I don't?

If someone could point me in the right direction as to what properties I have to account for in Windows that may be default in Linux/Mono, that would help a ton.

Comment: Is this a question about your program or why PuTTY sees different things on the two platforms?

Comment: A little from column A and a little from column B.  :)  The PuTTY discussion is more my trying to figure out why the code appear to behave differently depending on what is being asked for.  There is some sort of difference between the default state of the Windows and Linux Serial ports.  If I can get some information on that, I might be able to figure this out.

Comment: D'oh!  Missed a control line on the device.  :(  Needed to pull it high.  Did so and it's working correctly now.  Thanks for considering my question.